# unitTest Module for import module

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am new with creating unittest cases for my python scripts and i was wondering on how we can create test cases for our flask application. below are sample flask application that i have created.

Point 2 : When i check on my sonarScan , i will have to cover test cases in all scenarios even with import sys,os os path etc etc.

I am unsure on how to even start on creating this test cases .

Below is my run.py file

```
import sys , os , os.path , time , datetime , json , logging, warnings
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import url_for
from flask import request

from datetime import datetime
from logging import FileHandler
from logging import Formatter


## --> Create another function from a different .python file to import data

host_url="localhost"
port_number=1234
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    server='Development_Sandbox'
    return render_template('index.html',server=server)


@app.route('/information/')
@app.route('/information/<name>')
def information():
    name='summary_report'
    return render_template('information.html',name=name)

app.run(host='localhost', port=1234, debug=True)
```

based on my findings on creating test cases on python documents , i have created a simple test cases below for my flask application . However , i am not sure if this is the right approach.

e.g file test_flask.py

```
import unittest
import test
import sys
# from unittest import TestCase, mock

sys.path.insert(1, 'C:/Users/mm13854/Desktop/Python Project/subscription_app')
import run as flk

class Test_Flask(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_checkURL(self):
        result=flk.host_url
        self.assertEqual(result, 'localhost')

    def test_checkPortNumber(self):
        result=flk.port_number
        self.assertEqual(result, 1234)
    
    def test_importModules(self):
        #how do i test if import is succesful for example 
        #import sys ,import os , os.path , time , datetime , json , logging, warnings
        #from os import listdir
        #from os.path import isfile, join


if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: If there is code in the module that you are testing then you are implicitly already testing the imports since all your tests would fail if the imports did not work.

Comment: _I am unsure on how we can test import modules_ What exactly do you mean by "test import modules"?  Do you just want confirmation that the `import` statement was successful?  Or do you want to actually inspect the imported module to verify that it has some specific attribute?

Comment: i have edited my question to make it clearer , i am not sure if i am doing it right to create unit test cases.